# Checking Checkboxes based on Dropdown ISSUE

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code to check certain checkboxes based on the selected value of a dropdown. Problem is, They are almost cancelling eachother out. If I only put one in there it works fine. Even if I put two in it works fine. When I put all 7 javascript items however, It starts acting weird and when I select some dropdown values nothing gets checked.. or only some get checked.. It's really weird.

Below is the code.

Selector Code:

```
<select class='form-control' id='department' name='department' placeholder='Department'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
</select>
```

Brief example of the checkboxes. I have 36 of them, Only posting 1-8 so I don't make this post huge.

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2' for='id_comments'>Inccident</label>
    <div class='col-md-6'>

        <label for="ck1">Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ck1"  id="ck1">

        <label for="ck2">Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="ck2" id="ck2">

        <label for="ck3">Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="ck3" id="ck3">

        <label for="ck4">Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="ck4" id="ck4">

        <label for="ck5">Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="ck5" id="ck5">

        <label for="ck6">Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="ck6" id="ck6">

        <label for="ck7">Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="ck7" id="ck7">

        <label for="ck8">Test</label>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="ck8" id="ck8">

    </div>
</div>
```

Finally the JavaScript codes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#department").change(function() {
        var text = $('#department :selected').text();
        $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck15, #ck18, #ck16, #ck20, #ck1, #ck8, #ck6, #ck5, #ck21, #ck22').prop('checked', text === '1');
    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#department").change(function() {
        var text = $('#department :selected').text();
        $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck12, #ck16, #ck17, #ck18, #ck2, #ck4, #ck7, #ck23, #ck25, #ck33, #ck35, #ck36, #ck20').prop('checked', text === '2');
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#department").change(function() {
        var text = $('#department :selected').text();
        $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck12, #ck20, #ck23, #ck25, #ck26, #ck27, #ck28, #ck35, #ck36').prop('checked', text === '3');
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#department").change(function() {
        var text = $('#department :selected').text();
        $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck1, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck12, #ck13, #ck15, #ck16, #ck18, #ck20').prop('checked', text === '4');
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#department").change(function() {
        var text = $('#department :selected').text();
        $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck3, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck12, #ck13, #ck15, #ck16, #ck20, #ck21, #ck22, #ck23, #ck34').prop('checked', text === '5');
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#department").change(function() {
        var text = $('#department :selected').text();
        $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck3, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck13, #ck21, #ck20, #ck22, #ck23, #ck29, #ck30, #ck31, #ck32').prop('checked', text === '6');
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#department").change(function() {
        var text = $('#department :selected').text();
        $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck3, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck20, #ck21, #ck22, #ck23, #ck24, #ck25, #ck34').prop('checked', text === '7');
    });
</script>
```

I know I can put them all in one script tag. It was NOT working when I originally did that so I ended up putting them all like this too see if it works. Still acting funky.

**UPDATE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#department").change(function() {
      var text = $('#department :selected').text();
      $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck15, #ck18, #ck16, #ck20, #ck1, #ck8, #ck6, #ck5, #ck21, #ck22').prop('checked', text === '1');

      $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck12, #ck16, #ck17, #ck18, #ck2, #ck4, #ck7, #ck23, #ck25, #ck33, #ck35, #ck36, #ck20').prop('checked', text === '2');

      $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck12, #ck20, #ck23, #ck25, #ck26, #ck27, #ck28, #ck35, #ck36').prop('checked', text === '3');

      $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck1, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck12, #ck13, #ck15, #ck16, #ck18, #ck20').prop('checked', text === '4');

       $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck3, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck12, #ck13, #ck15, #ck16, #ck20, #ck21, #ck22, #ck23, #ck34').prop('checked', text === '5');

      $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck3, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck13, #ck21, #ck20, #ck22, #ck23, #ck29, #ck30, #ck31, #ck32').prop('checked', text === '6');

      $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck3, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck20, #ck21, #ck22, #ck23, #ck24, #ck25, #ck34').prop('checked', text === '7');
});

</script>
```

Did it like this aswell, Same issue.

Comment: Please _Don't Repeat Yourself!_ In code as well as questions :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @Kevin, I am not sure about questions.. But damn sure about _CODE_!

Comment: Instead of having 10 listeners, you should have 1 listener that handles all the permutations

Comment: @RayonDabre Enlighten me were I duplicated this code.... Show me ONE post where I used this. I didn't.

Comment: @tik27 I did it like that originally and it still didn't work. I thought maybe that was the issue and that's why I changed it to be like this. Still same issue.

Comment: @Kevin, You didn't duplicate! You repeated... No more arguments..

Comment: @RayonDabre If you are talking about the JS, Yes I did. Please read my entire post to figure out why. I did NOT repeat at first. Still same issue.

Comment: @RayonDabre Updated to what you are talking about... As you can see, still not working.

Comment: @Kevin, Just tell us your requirement in simple words..Checkbox should get selected based on the option ?

Comment: @RayonDabre My goodness man, lol. Ok. When I select a different value in the dropdown. It should check each checkbox that corrorsponds to that dropdown value. If I only add one line of the javascript say for only if the selected value === 1 then it works.. But if I add all 7 like above.. Then it stop working all the way on some, and other are missing tons of checks.

Comment: Like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ov6z2L3a/1/

Comment: @RayonDabre  How do you assign certain values though. If the selected value of the dropdown == 1 I want it to check boxes 1-6 else if the value == 2 I want it to check boxes 4-8 and so on.

Comment: @Kevin Use data-collection attribute which could be easily selected..

Comment: @RayonDabre I edited this jsfiddle, can you tell me why it does not de-select when I switch the dropdown...

Comment: @RayonDabre https://jsfiddle.net/ov6z2L3a/2/

Comment: Selector is wrong.. It must be`SELECT_ID option:selected`

Answer (score 1):

Thank too RayonDabre and my own brain. I have got it resolved.

Here is the jquery that lets it work properly.

```
$('#department').change(function() {
var select = $('#department :selected');
var id = select.attr('id');

if(select.val() == '1') {
        $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);


    $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck15, #ck18, #ck16, #ck20, #ck1, #ck8, #ck6, #ck5, #ck21, #ck22').prop('checked', true);
}

else if(select.val() == '2')
{
    $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);

    $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck12, #ck16, #ck17, #ck18, #ck2, #ck4, #ck7, #ck23, #ck25, #ck33, #ck35, #ck36, #ck20').prop('checked', true);
}
else if(select.val() == '3')
{
    $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck12, #ck20, #ck23, #ck25, #ck26, #ck27, #ck28, #ck35, #ck36').prop('checked', true);
}
else if(select.val() == '4')
{
$('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck1, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck12, #ck13, #ck15, #ck16, #ck18, #ck20').prop('checked', true);
}
else if(select.val() == '5')
{
    $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck3, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck12, #ck13, #ck15, #ck16, #ck20, #ck21, #ck22, #ck23, #ck34').prop('checked', true);
}
else if(select.val() == '6')
{
    $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck3, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck13, #ck21, #ck20, #ck22, #ck23, #ck29, #ck30, #ck31, #ck32').prop('checked', true);
}
else if(select.val() == '7')
{
    $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('#ck9, #ck10, #ck11, #ck3, #ck5, #ck6, #ck8, #ck20, #ck21, #ck22, #ck23, #ck24, #ck25, #ck34').prop('checked', true);
}
```

});

Comment: Though it works well.. Using `data-*` attribute will make it look better!